# Terminator 2: Judgement Day: T-800 John Connor Acquisition

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

How does the T-800 find John Connor? Unlike the T-1000, in [my previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94053/john-connor-acquirement-by-t-1000), there was no address to which he knew where to find him. Of course, we could say that John Connor or if we're going by T-3, Katherine Brewster, told the T-800 where John Connor lived.

When I say "how did he know where to find him?" I am also wondering how it would have found him at the mall, out of all places.

Answer (score 16):

Connor sent the T-800 back to protect his earlier self.

> **T-800:** My mission is to protect you.
>
> **CONNOR:** Yeah?  Who sent you?
>
> **T-800:** You did.  Thirty-five years from now you reprogrammed me to be your protector here, in this time.

Connor of course knew where he was living in 1994 and the likely places he would be hanging out then.  Obviously he would give the T-800 that information.  The T-1000 didn't have the advantage of that inside information, so it had to use other means to locate Connor.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Time travel paradoxes make my brain hurt, but I never thought that future John had gone through the stuff that T2/1994 John did.  I assumed they were on different timelines.

Comment: @Andrew If future Connor remembered the T-800's visit he would have also remembered Dyson's horrible death at the hands of the SWAT team.  I think Connor would have found a way to spare Dyson in that case.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - You're going an awfully long way to get your theory to make sense.  It seems infinitely easier to just assume that future John didn't go through the events of T2 himself.  He just knew that Skynet had sent the T1000 to kill his past self, so he sent his own Terminator back to stop the T1000.